# I don't know what is my audio device and there is no sound on Ubuntu 11

Tags: sound, realtek

I have a little bit strange Desktop. It is a HP Compaq desktop with all its components enclosed by the factory(like a laptop). I don't know what the audio and video devices are but on Windows I just put the GIGABYTE definition CD and it does all the work for me.

Now, how can I do such a thing on Ubuntu 11 ?!

The only thing I miss on Ubuntu is audio. I can't play any music or video !!

A thing I think it will be useful is that before I install Ubuntu and erase Windows, the Audio device or something like that was "Realtek Sound Effec Manager". I copied the name.

How can I play audio on my PC ?!

Comment: Take a look at the output of `lspci`.

Comment: Two things, try a search here for '[Realtek](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=Realtek)' to see what issues you might be facing, and download a newer version of Ubuntu. [12.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) is the current version and it's the best choice unless you have a specific reason for not using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Realtek sound card. Type in a terminal

```
lspci
```

It will show you your sound card and other devices attached with your computer.

To install Realtek driver you can download the package from their website.

[Click to download](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2)

Extract it and click install. Then reboot your system.

Comment: This is the audio device I seem o have "Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)"
What should I do ?!

Comment: You can do two things. 1) Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or 2) Try to installing realtek driver. Installing this driver will be ok. I have HP Compaq CQ42 with realtek. But 'lspci' show exect thing. But i install latest driver of realtek. Try to install this driver 1st. If it don't work install  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It will fix most of your driver problem.