# Toshiba Satellite M115 sound issue in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: realtek

I have seen similar problems on this site and on others, and I have tried all sorts of solutions posted, but so far non have worked. I have a Toshiba Satellite M115-S1061 that came with Windows XP. I want to learn Linux so I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the sound isn't not working correctly. It worked fine on Windows XP beforehand. I have also tried Linux Mint on this machine with the same results. I can very faintly hear sound if I plug in headphones, but nothing comes out of the speakers.

When I open the Sound Settings, there is nothing listed in the Play Through box under the Output Tab. I click "Test Sound" and nothing happens. Under the Applications Tab it shows ALSA plugin [plug-in container]. The volume for that is all the way up, however, at the bottom of the window it says Output volume, and that's all way down and I can't adjust it.

I have no idea how to solve this and I really would like to have sound coming through the speakers and more volume coming out of the headphones.

Comment: I had also same problem. The solution from [this post][1] worked for me.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/157738/i-dont-know-what-is-my-audio-device-and-there-is-no-sound-on-ubuntu-11

Comment: Have you tried upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer requires a proprietary driver which you can download here:

http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2